# Load Angular data after DOM

Tags: javascript, angular

I am looking for a way to speed up my website by loading content that is not required to display the main DOM afterwards.
My webpage is loading 2.8MB of ressources where 879kB are actually transferred. (gzip)
I am aware of the possibility of loading only the required components, but if I do so, I'll have the same problem after a user clicks any link to another component.
Basically what I want to do is loading my main component and displaying the DOM immediately.
After DOM is loaded, I want to load the other components as usual.
Is there a NPM package that does this?
If not, how can I realise my desire?

Comment: Have you tried with lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy loading modules to load them only if needed. It will greatly decrease bundle size:

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Application should be split to separate modules and routing is modified not to load them eagerly

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like server side rendering. You should check out Angular Universal.

https://angular.io/guide/universal